# How to cache jars for DataProc Spark job submission

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I am submitting a Spark job to Dataproc using either gcloud or Google Cloud DataProc API. One of the arguments is '--jars' (or its Java API equivalent), where I supply comma separated list of jar files to be provided to the executor and driver classpaths:

gs://google-storage-bucket/lib/x1.jar,gs://google-storage-bucket/lib/x2.jar, etc...

Same JAR files are copied from Google storage bucket to the working directory for each SparkContext on the executor nodes every time I submit a job and it takes about 2 minutes, before the job really starts execution (I can see that on the Google Cloud console - https://console.cloud.google.com/dataproc/jobs/...).

Is it possible to somehow cache these jar files on Spark nodes and use them in the classpath with every job submission? That would save about 50% of the run time.

Thanks,

Victor

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, if you pass in arguments of the form `file:///your/path/on/the/cluster/nodes/filesystem` then it will be interpreted as referring to files on the cluster nodes themselves.

You can either copy files from GCS into the nodes at cluster creation time using an initiailization action or try to run some kind of Spark job to do it on an existing cluster and/or manually SSH'ing in to stage those jars.